# Application using dll with Catel crashed after use PleaseWaitService

Tags: c#, catel

I am using Catel 4.1 in dll running from another application. When I use `PleaseWaitService.Show` in dll, application used dll is crashed on close.

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly IPleaseWaitService _waitService;

    public MainViewModel(IPleaseWaitService waitService)
    {
        _waitService = waitService;
        _waitService.Show(LoadRecData, "Load State...");
        // LoadRecData(); Ends without crash
    }
 }
```

When I use just `LoadRecData()` application ends without crash..
This happens even if the method `LoadRecData()` is empty.
NET Framework 4.5.1

What could be the problem?

Comment: For starters show us the exception with the stack trace and then add any relevant code.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.CannotUnloadAppDomainException' occurred in mscorlib.dll. I can't handle it and get stack trace.

Comment: We need more information. Please create a repro and upload it to the official issue tracker. It could really by anything.

Comment: I use the dll from MapInfo and the root of all evil .. Perhaps it is necessary to use a new application domain and run code from under him..